# What is the need of LSA refresh after every 30 minutes?

Tags: ospf

What is the exact need of LSA being refreshed every 30 minutes.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

30 minutes is the hard, maximum limit between distinct originations of any LSA. After this time, a new origination must be sent as the old one times out, see [RFC 2328](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328#page-217).

That timeout is just a sanity limit and it prevents stale records to accumulate in any router. Usually, all changes have been propagated long before.